# Trying to get IP of other devices connected to the same WIFI network

Tags: java, networking, ip, wifi

In the following code I am trying to verify the availability of devices sharing the same WIFI network but when I run it nothing is being printed in the console and the program just pauses for a while and closes. Am I checking with the wrong address in the first place or the wrong way all-together ?
If so then what would be a correct way of doing this in Java ?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class net_chat {
    public static void checkHosts(String subnet){
        int timeout=1000;
        for (int i=1;i<255;i++){
            String host=subnet + "." + i;
            try{
            if (InetAddress.getByName(host).isReachable(timeout)){
                System.out.println(host + " is reachable");
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println( "None at " + host );
                }
        }
    }
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        checkHosts("192.168.0");
        }
}
```

Comment: The code does exactly what it aims to do. I think this is more of a ip problem. Do you have any 192.168.0.* address reachable at all?

Comment: Quote from the JavaDoc on `isReachable(timeout)`: "Best effort is made by the implementation to try to reach the host, but *firewalls and server configuration may block requests resulting in a unreachable status* while some specific ports may be accessible." So it could be the firewalls or configuration on your devices or network components.

Comment: Also note that `getByName()` only throws an exception if you're passing in an invalid ip address (i.e. wrong format). Since you're passing valid addresses you'll also not get any "None at ..." messages.